# LINQ. SubmitChanges() not updating database

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, linq

I can update the DataGrid when app is on but there are no updates in the database. So when I open app again I see objects that I added manualy to database using MS SQL.
Id does have a primary key.

```
private void AddEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dataClasses1DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                var newEmployee = new Employee
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(idTextBox.Text),
                    first_name = firstNameTextBox.Text,
                    last_name = lastNameTextBox.Text,
                    birth_day = DateTime.Parse(dateOfBirthTextBox.Text),
                    sex = char.Parse(SexTextBox.Text),
                    salary = int.Parse(SalaryTextBox.Text),
                    supervisor_id = int.Parse(SupervisorIdTextBox.Text),
                    branch_id = int.Parse(BranchIdTextBox.Text)
                };

                dataClasses1DataContext.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(newEmployee);
                dataClasses1DataContext.SubmitChanges();

                DataGridEmployees.ItemsSource = null;
                DataGridEmployees.ItemsSource = dataClasses1DataContext.Employees.ToList();

                MessageBox.Show("Employee Added Successfully");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Invalid Input Values");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not look like any recent version of EF.

Comment: In the `SubmitChanges` try passing a `ConflictMode` enum, what happens?

Comment: I tried passing a ConflictMode and.. still nothing :|

Comment: Double-check the `Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString` if point to the right db.

Comment: I've tripled-checked. It points to the right db. I can see all data from database in datagrid but I can't make any changes when I use submitChanges().

Comment: Whats the version from EntityFramework aqre you using?

Comment: It's not EntityFramework, I use Linq-to-SQL

Comment: I realized that when I debug/release my project, linq creates another databases related to debug/release in different (debug/release) folders. So I tried to modify my database and now it's working. My question is: is there any way to fix this and don't let linq creating another databases but stay connected to the only one?

Comment: As far as I know, Linq2Sql does not have the ability to create databases. I would suspect you are using an attached database which is located in your output folder and you also have an mdf file in your project with the properties set to always copy to your output folder. Hence every time you build your project, Visual Studio will copy this mdf file to your output folder.